# Can't access iDRAC9 Web UI

Tags: drac

I have a PowerEdge R640 server. I was previously able to access the Web UI, but now I just get a never ending spinning wheel. I can ping the IP & SSH into it, but I'm not sure what to do once I'm in. Any suggestions on how I can access the UI again?

[image: Web UI Screen Shot]

[image: SSH Screen shot]

Comment: Have you tried a different browser?

Comment: I have regular problems with Idrac web access, especially with Firefox. It helps to clean out the Firefox profile or use anonymous mode. I think it's related to a cluttered certificate database file and self signed certificates.

Answer (score 8):

First, did you try another browser or to clear your cache.

If yes, then please unplug the server completely to have the iDRAC reset and after please do firmware update if some update are available to it.

You can jump to the version [4.0.0.0](https://www.dell.com/support/home/ca/en/cabsdt1/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=4jcpk&oscode=biosa&productcode=poweredge-r640) if you can, it add stability to the iDRAC.

> iDRAC with Lifecycle Controller, 4.00.00.00 Fixes & Enhancements Fixes
>   - Stability and performance improvements

Answer (score 7):

Thanks for the help everyone. I had tired Chrome, Firefox & IE with & without private browsing with no luck. I just found this [link](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln305793/how-to-reset-the-internal-dell-remote-access-controller-idrac-on-a-poweredge-server?lang=en). I held down the "i" button on the front panel for 20 sec. and iDRAC reset itself without powering down the server or losing its configuration.

Comment: Why did you accept the wrong answer? You can and should accept the most valid option. In this case it seems you found it and it's perfectly fine to accept your own answer.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta, The system won't allow me to accept my own answer.

Comment: You need to wait 24 hours from memory, after you can accept your own answer without problem! Just a note, I would write that it reset the config too, It's not a big deal in most case, but it's better to know

Comment: @yagmoth555, It did not reset the config.

Comment: @BarryRalphs oh, cool then :) learnt a new tip then today

Answer (score 1):

An R640 is not that old, and certainly should work with modern browsers - the old java version requirements of older DRACs isn't yet a thing for DRAC9.

If you have physical access to the box (or competent smart-hands) then try ***draining the flea power*** and no I'm not making that name up.

The usual process is

1. Safely power off using the OS.
2. Then removed every power cable from the host (multiple PSUs are possible) and to also unpower any direct-attached components like disk shelves or PCIE expanders or any USB or serial device with its own power supply.   Ethernet switches are fine to ignore but console cables should be disconnected.
3. With the host completely stone dead, press and hold the host's front panel power button down for at least 30 seconds, then release. Make sure you get the correct host - in a rack of identical hardware its easy to get the wrong box.
4. Reconnect all device cables.
5. Reconnect all power cables.  You may have to start the host with a brief press of the power button.

Note I've never done this on 48V DC-powered kit - on these the power leads are generally hard wired to the PSU.  Be extra careful if you have DC power.

It may sound ridiculous, but this has been a "last resort" option that can fix the weirdest problems which have survived complete reboots of the host.

Comment: IDRAC8 do also,come with the HTML5 alternative zu Java. And you can just DRAC instead.

Answer (score 0):

IDRAC can share a NIC with the OS, in past people have used a dedicated port, so if you are only using the one NIC something to be aware of, it will have two IP addresses, one for the IDRAC and for the Host OS. Most switches by default will not send and receive data for the same network to the same port, this behaviour is normal. This only causes an issue when you trying to essential loop back to the same port but a different IP within the same network. If you configure IDRAC to use a VLAN and setup VLAN routing between the two networks this solves this problem.

Simliar issue listed here.
[iDRAC6 with shared LOM - can't access web login from same machine](https://www.dell.com/community/Systems-Management-General/iDRAC6-with-shared-LOM-can-t-access-web-login-from-same-machine/td-p/4141937)

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this question when diagnosing a similar problem on one of the newer versions of iDRAC (I think it was iDRAC 14). I tried updating and this didn't help. Eventually I noticed that the URL in the browser was using port 5900, which I had no firewall exception for. Adding a firewall exception / port forward for TCP port 5900 might help.